# Get value from autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to assign value from dropdown to autocomplete textbox ..till Now I have done this

---

---

[image]

---

---

But You can see I can't assign  value from Dropdown to textbox ..
I have implemented auto complete feature by a JQuery PlugIn "Prop.js"

this is the code I have created

```
  <link href="~/Content/popr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/popr.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/popr.min.js"></script>

 <div id="address" >

 <label>Country</label>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Country")</td>
            <td>
                <div class="popr" data-id="demo">^</div>
                <div class="popr-box" data-box-id="demo">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Country").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Location/GetAllCountry",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);

                }
            })
        },
        appendTo: '#menu-container',
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Location/GetAllCountry",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { term: "" },
        success: function (states) {

            var $select = $('div[data-box-id="demo"]');
            $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                $('<option>', {
                    value: state
                }).html(state).appendTo($select)
                .addClass("popr-item");
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr) { alert("Something seems Wrong"); }
    });

});

$('.popr').popr();


$('.popr').popr({
    'speed': 200,
    'mode': 'bottom'
});
```

I have searched the solution the tried for a click inside div to get selected value

```
$(".popr-item").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

});

$(".popr-box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("popr-box");
});
```

this is not working

I tried another plugin "chosen" .. But it fails in cascading dropdown ..I am not in a position to try another plugin ... I strictly want to use by this way

if there is another plugin available , I need to see example with cascading dropdown specifically

I just need selected value from dropdown , How Can I achieve this ?

Comment: Try this and see if the `alert()` gets called:

`$('body').on("click", ".popr-box", function(){ alert('test'); });`

Answer (score 0):

Add this select option in autocomplete

```
$("#Country").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Location/GetAllCountry",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);

                }
            })
        },
              select: function( event, ui ) {
                            $( "#Country" ).val( ui.item.label );
                            return false;
                        },
        appendTo: '#menu-container',
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
```